# How can I show the author in-text citations abbreviated from organisation full-name in .bib file? (Quarto)

Tags: r, quarto, bibtex

I am using RStudio Quarto to create html file. This is my first time using R and Quarto to create any documents. I managed to create `citations.bib` file including information of all references and downloaded csl file for the format. They are included in YAML as follows:

```
bibliography: citations.bib
csl: harvard-university-of-XXXX.csl
```

My question here is how I can edit the author of in-text citations to use the abbreviation (e.g., UN in text but United Nations in the bibliography).

For example in my working, the following is one of the references in my .bib file.

```
@misc{FuelPovertyStat2024,
  title        = "Fuel poverty statistics",
  author       = "{Department for Energy Security and Net Zero} and {Department for Business, Energy \& Industrial Strategy}",
  shortauthor  = "{DESNZ} and {BEIS}",
  year         = 2024,
  note         = "Accessed: 2024-01-25"
}
```

In the reference list, I would like it to be as follows:
(and it is coming correctly)

> Department for Energy Security and Net Zero and Department for Business, Energy & Industrial Strategy, 2024. Fuel poverty statistics.

But, in the text, I would want it to be shown as

> text..blah...blah (DESNZ and BEIS, 2024).

As you can see in the example .bib file entry, I tried adding a `shortauthor =`  field reading another thread but I must be missing something as it is not working.

Could you please help me here? I am still new in this world so any basic-level explanation would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you would just write `[@FuelPovertyStat2024]`  where you want the citation to appear in the text.

Comment: @AllanCameron Hi, yes, [...] makes the citation appear, but it appears as (Department for Energy Security and Net Zero and Department for Business, Energy & Industrial Strategy, 2024), not (DESNZ and BEIS, 2024) as I wish.